# GADTs with single constructor

Tags: haskell, types

Here's a sample code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data NumGadt a where
  NumGadt :: Num a => a -> Int -> String -> Bool -> NumGadt a

getNum :: NumGadt a -> a
getNum (NumGadt a _ _ _) = a
```

Now let's say I want to write a function like this:

```hs
successor :: NumGadt a -> a
successor x = 1 + getNum x
```

The problem is this would not compile, with an error about `No instance for (Num a)`

A possible solution to this would be

```hs
successor :: NumGadt a -> a
successor x@(NumGadt _ _ _ _) = 1 + getNum x
```

but this is rather ugly, and using this in more places would become really ugly.

So question is, is there some way to make the compiler realize that there is only one constructor for this type, and infer constraints from it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question really has to do with GADTs (this example certainly doesn't need one, you can just use a regular ADT with a single constructor). The problem is just that you haven't specified the necessary `Num a` constraint on the signature of `successor`.

Comment: Did you forget a `Num a` constraint in the type of the constructor?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot `Num a` in type constructor, my bad.

Comment: The common way is to put the constraint on functions. You might want to explain why you need to do such an unconventional thing as putting a constraint in a constructor, because otherwise it looks like you're only creating more problems for yourself.

Comment: Short version, I'm trying to make a frontend for tensorflow, with shapes of tensors controlled at compile time. For that I'm using singletons, and I need `SingI shape` to be derived in many places. Trying to avoid too many function constraint, I decided to make tensors contain singletons of their shapes. Still, sometimes `SingI s` is required, and being able to easily derive it from the context would be nice.

Comment: The compiler *can* infer the constraint, but you are overriding its inferred type by explicitly providing the type `NumGadt a -> a` (which is just short for `forall a . NumGadt a -> a`). You aren't asking about type inference, but about changing the semantics of the implicitly quantified type variable `a`.

Answer (score 6):

You could define a `withNum` helper which brings the `Num a` dictionary in scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}

data NumGadt a where
  NumGadt :: Num a => a -> Int -> String -> Bool -> NumGadt a

withNum :: NumGadt a -> (Num a => b) -> b
withNum (NumGadt _ _ _ _) y = y

getNum :: NumGadt a -> a
getNum (NumGadt a _ _ _) = a

successor :: NumGadt a -> a
successor x = withNum x (1 + getNum x)
```

In my view this is not much better than matching against the constructor in `successor`, even if the name `withNum` is more self-documenting.

Note that you can even use the shorter record syntax:

```
successor :: NumGadt a -> a
successor x@NumGadt{} = 1 + getNum x
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `{}` pattern doesn't require record syntax in the type.